# How to execute action on GET request with f:viewParam?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm currently trying out sending the id of a record from one page to another page.

So in the page 1, i have something like this :

```
<p:column>
    <h:link value="#{rpb.map['transNum']}" outcome="TInput.xhtml">
        <f:param name="id" value="#{rpb.map['id']}" />
    </h:link>
</p:column>
```

and in the target page (TInput.xhtml), i have something like this to capture the id :

```
....
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions">

<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{tInputBean.id}"></f:viewParam>
</f:metadata>

<h:head>
....
```

Now, clicking on the link, goes to page 2, and page 2 is handled by one view-scoped jsf bean. And from my debugging, this is the order of happenning :

1. the @PostConstruct method is executed
2. the model is updated with the id captured from the viewParam (after appy request + validation)

What i would like to achieve is that : 
**after the model is updated, i would like to execute a query for that record id, get it's bean and it's list of details from Business Service.**

I wonder where should i could put my query code :

1. inside @PostConstruct method is not possible, since the id captured from the viewParam is set to the model **after** the @PostConstruct method finishes
2. use a phase listener on after the model update ?
3. use a system event ? although i cant seem to find the appropriate one for this case

Please enlighten me :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a [`<f:event type="preRenderView">`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/f/event.html) to the [`<f:metadata>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/f/metadata.html).

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{tInputBean.id}" />
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{tInputBean.init}" />
</f:metadata>
```

with a

```
public void init(ComponentSystemEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {
    // ...
}
```

*(by the way, in contrary to the documentation, the argument and the exception are optional, at least in all Mojarra 2.x versions I've had used)*

Comment: @BalusC: Thank you so much! I just know today that we can put the event tag inside the f:metadata. So, basically, regardless of whether im using GET or POST, i can always make use of the f:event inside f:metadata to call methods according to the event type, am i correct ?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, it's regardless of the method. However, such a page with `f:metadata` should preferably be used for GET requests only.

Comment: @BalusC: Hello again ! I wonder, if f:metadata is preferably be used for GET method only, what is the recommended approach to be able to execute a method on a pre-render event with a POST method ?

Comment: The command link/button action method. Without `f:metadata`. Thus, "the usual way" :)

Comment: @BalusC: aha! the englightening moment ! Thank you BalusC .. :-)

Comment: @BalusC: Ah .. found a little trouble with this. Every ajax call like when i'm using auto completion, doing partial submit and then refreshing using ajax, the listener will also run. Is there a trick to avoid the listener running while doing ajax stuffs ? Thank you !

Comment: Check if `FacesContext#isPostback()` returns true, then it's an (ajax) postback request.

Comment: @BalusC: Ah, the documentation imcompleteness! Many times I have been confused due to the documentation not being correct. It does make it hard for new Java starters.

Answer (score 4):

I used the BalusC solution. Thanks;)

I just want to add if you use facelet, you need to put :

```
 <f:metadata>
```

in each page using the template:

mytemplate.xhtml:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<ui:insert name="meta"/>
```

mypage.xhtml using mytemplate.xhtml:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<ui:composition template="mytemplate">

 <ui:define name="meta">
    <f:metadata>
       <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{tInputBean.id}" />
       <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{tInputBean.init}" />
     </f:metadata>
  </ui:define>
...
```

Solution found at : https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2145709