# Does it matter whether place f:event inside f:metadata or not?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets

w.r.t. [How to execute action on GET request with f:viewParam?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647679/how-to-execute-action-on-get-request-with-fviewparam/7343191#7343191)

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{tInputBean.id}" />
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{tInputBean.init}" />
</f:metadata>
```

I'm interested to know whether it matters if a `preRenderView` `f:event` is placed inside the f:metadata or not. I've checked the Java EE6 tutorial, Java Server Faces 2.0 Complete Reference, and Core JSF2, and none of them have examples of f:event inside f:metadata, but I've seen lots of examples online like this.

JSF2 Compl.Ref says p.540

> The f:metadata tag encapsulates the set of elements used to specify
>   the metadata for a Facelet view, and therefore must be a child of the
>   f:view tag and may not appear in a template. As of JSF2.0, the only
>   purpose of this tag is to encapsulate f:viewParam tags.

Does placing the f:event (often used to support an f:viewParam) inside the f:metadata have a special meaning, or is it just to help group it alongside the f:viewParam visually/logically ?

Answer (score 8):

No, the [`<f:event>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/event.html) is not strictly required to be placed inside [`<f:metadata>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/metadata.html). It can be attached to any component. It's indeed for pure self-documentary purposes placed inside the `<f:metadata>` whenever you have a bunch of [`<f:viewParam>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/viewParam.html)s and would like to hook a `<f:event>` to invoke an action after all those view parameters have been set. It can even be placed outside/before those `<f:viewParam>`s, but it makes the code not more self-documenting.

Note that in the upcoming JSF 2.2, a new `<f:viewAction>` tag will be introduced which in turn is supposed to replace the `<f:event type="preRenderView">` in the `<f:metadata>`.

Comment: Thanks BalusC. I have since found that it does seem to matter whether one places an f:event inside an f:metadata of a template (only): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11069484/jsf-fevent-prerenderview-in-template-fmetadata-listener-not-being-called-on-e