# How to start special init event in a backing bean before JSF page loads?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, cdi

PF 3.5.10, Mojarra 2.1.21, Omnifaces 1.5

How to call special init()-method of some (CDI)SessionScoped bean before I load a .xhtml JSF page ? Now I call init() if user select the page from site menu (with `p:menutitem`). But what to do if the user use browser address line to type url directly?

Edit: `my.xhtml`:

```
<ui:define template="/mytemp.xhtml">
   <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{mybean.init()}" />
   <h:form>
     <p:commandButton update="@form" ... />
   </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

If I do it that way the init() will be called on every update (i.e. on every postback to a server),in example on every click of commandButton. So I can not use your proposal.

Edit 2: Thank you Luiggi Mendoza, and BalusC! 
In addtion to solution from Luiggi Mendoza, as in comments stated the Omnifaces 1.6 will be  have ViewScope also.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that the `@PostConstruct public void init()` method is called after the managed bean is created and the fields are injected. Since your bean is `@SessionScoped`, it will live until the user session expires.

A way to solve is to use `<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="{bean.init}" />` as explained here: [What can <f:metadata>, <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6377798/1065197) (no need to use `<f:metadata>` as explained by BalusC here: [Does it matter whether place f:event inside f:metadata or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7343220/1065197)).

Per your question update, this problem is handled in the first link. I'll post the relevant code to handle this situation (taken from BalusC answer):

```
public void init() {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    if (!facesContext.isPostback() && !facesContext.isValidationFailed()) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

If you migrate to JSF 2.2, then there's [a `@ViewScoped` annotation for CDI beans](http://jdevelopment.nl/jsf-22/#1087) and you could reduce the scope of your `@SessionScoped` beans accordingly.

Comment: [`<f:event>` does not necessarily need to go inside `<f:metadata>`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343220/jsf-does-it-matter-whether-place-fevent-inside-fmetadata-or-not/)

Comment: By the way, OmniFaces 1.6 will come with a CDI compatible `@ViewScoped` for JSF 2.0/2.1.

Comment: @BalusC your last commet is great news. I'll wait for and try it.

Comment: This is already answered/explained in "What can <f:metadata> and <f:viewParam> be used for?" link :)

Comment: @BalusC Ok, I see. I should make a postback check in an init(). I will try it.