# Simulation of f:viewAction on master page template

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, viewaction

There is an application scoped bean.

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class Bean {

    @Inject
    private Service service;
    private Entity entity; // Getter.
    // Entity is periodically fetched by EJB timers on the server side
    // which when fetched notifies associated clients through WebSockets.
    // Clients then update themselves by sending an AJAX request.
    // All of these things collectively form a different chapter.
    // Just that update() needs to be invoked, when a client sends a synchronous GET request

    public Bean() {}

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        consume();
    }

    private void consume() {
        entity = service.getEntity();
    }

    public void update() {
        consume();
        System.out.println("update called.");
    }
}
```

This bean is accessed by a page included in the master template as follows (`West.xhtml`) :

```
<html lang="#{localeBean.language}"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

    <h:form>
        <!-- This is merely a fake attempt to show something like this is expected. -->
        <ui:define name="metaData">
            <f:metadata>
                <f:viewAction action="{bean.update}"/>
            </f:metadata>
        </ui:define>

        <h:outputText value="#{bean.entity.field}"/>
    </h:form>
</html>
```

There is a false attempt to invoke the `update()` method by using `<f:viewAction>` from the master template which is against its semantics.

For this to function, the `<f:viewAction>` needs to be repeated on individual template clients which makes it difficult to maintain, especially when something needs to be changed.

Is there any possibility to avoid `<f:viewAction>` being repeated all over the place on every template client?

---

The master page template looks like the following. It is not required. Just assume that the above page is included using `<ui:include src=".."/>` in the following master template (`/WEB-INF/templates/Template.xhtml`).

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

    <f:view locale="..." ...>
        <ui:insert name="metaData"></ui:insert>

        <h:head>
            <title><ui:insert name="title">Default Title</ui:insert></title>
        </h:head>

        <h:body>
            <h:panelGroup layout="block">
                <ui:insert name="contentBar">
                    <!-- The file given above is included here - West.xhtml. -->
                    <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/template/contents/West.xhtml"/>
                </ui:insert>
            </h:panelGroup>

            <ui:insert name="content">Default contents</ui:insert>

            <!--Other content bars.-->
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

`<f:viewAction>` needs to be placed on template clients associated something like the following.

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/Template.xhtml"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

    <ui:define name="title">Page Title</ui:define>

    <ui:define name="metaData">
        <f:metadata>
            <f:viewAction action="#{bean.update}"/>
        </f:metadata>
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="content">
        <!--Main contents-->
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

And so forth, `<f:viewAction>` needs to be repeated on every such template client for it to do its coherent task.

Is there a way to declare `<f:viewAction>` appropriately at a single place so that there is no need to repeat it on every associated template client?

Comment: There are couple of things I don't understand from this question. Why to declare a template client named West and then use it in a `ui:include` instead of giving it an standard template functionality? Also I don't understand what you mean with `false attempt to invoke`.

Comment: `West.xhtml` is not a template client. It is an included page using `<ui:include src="..."/>` Template clients are kept aside from the question - they are not mentioned at all in the question. "*false attempt to invoke*" means unless that method is declared and thus repeated on every template client, it is not invoked because `<f:viewAction>` needs to be declared on template clients associated. Thus, it violates rules. The question was whether it is possible to declare `<f:viewAction>` at a single place or not so that there is no need repeat it all over the place on every template client.

Comment: OK, so still don't understand why you use an included page (with `<ui:include src="..."/>`) to refer to a concrete template client issue. The `f:viewAction` is supposed to be placed in `f:metadata` and this goes in the top level view, meaning the template client. You [cannot use](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9857186/1199132) `f:metadata` in a master template. You [could](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343220/does-it-matter-whether-place-fevent-inside-fmetadata-or-not/7343242#7343242) instead place a `f:event` in the master template.

Comment: Yes it is not the place where `<f:metadata>` can reside or be placed. It is merely a fake attempt to show something like that is needed. I see placing `<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bean.listener}"/>` on the master template has some issues. It also invokes, when some portion on `West.xhtml` is periodically updated via `<p:remoteCommand>` through WebSockets and it invokes  multiple times. Its invocation is completely unnecessary, when something is updated otherwise.