# JSF - f:event body - after DOM load

Tags: jsf, dom, jsf-2, jstl, facelets

I am wondering about [f:event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7343242/7856725) location and sub tags; I googled a lot but couldn't find `f:event` to be used **with its body subtags** something like this (see code snippet) :

```
<f:event type="postAddToView"...>
<c:set var="myVar" value="#{aBean.aProperty}">    
</f:event>
```

...so to call bean after DOM loaded or similar? I mean how to use `f:event` exactly to init `c:set` after DOM is loaded? And is it possible to catch the event with JSF?

Thanks

Comment: You seem to be looking for a solution in a certain direction while I think you problem is more generic in nature: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588327/how-to-invoke-a-jsf-managed-bean-on-a-html-dom-event-using-native-javascript

Comment: No, I am looking for on-dom-loaded-event-catch-on-jsf optimal solution. Something like the javascript's `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { 
 
 }, false);` solution is

Comment: Yes and if you read the 'duplicate' good enough,  that is exactly what you can achieve...

Comment: @Kukeltje the solution describes a 'hack' way but is there a standard one?

Comment: 1 is a hack, 2, 3 and 4 are the normal solutions. Of which 4 is standardized and 2 and 3 are its predecessors.

Comment: @Kukeltje Currently I am using JSF itself not it's based libs so is there a standard way for JSF?

Comment: Number 4... (but including omnifaces is always good)

Comment: @Kukeltje but I asked about the f:event body; So will (see question) c:set be exec-ed on to the `postAddToView` event for example?

Comment: Yes, but that is all server side... all before any html is sent to the client, so no relation at all to any client-side dom events. That's why I stated you most likely have an xy problem and I focussed on the dom part and then the `f:event` does not play any role. As long as your functional requirement is not clarified, the answer to _"...so to call bean after DOM loaded or similar?"_ is what I stated