# h:outputLink navigation sometimes does not work

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, seam2

I have a navigation define from one page to another like this.

```
<h:outputLink id="idLink"  value="Page1.seam" >
    <f:param name="m" value="n103" />
    <f:param name="mss" value="110" />
<h:outputText value="Return to Page 1" />
<a4j:support event="onclick" action="#{beanName.action}" limitToList="true" ignoreDupResponses="true" eventsQueue="que" ajaxSingle="true" immediate="true">
</a4j:support>
</h:outputLink>
```

The problem is there are sometimes that the view isn't changing to Page1.seam and remain in Page2.seam.
Is there anyone who knows better ? 
Help will be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: What do you do in beanName.action? Post some code. Do you get any error or logs when it fails? Check the action in your browser. Is he doing a post. You can check with firebug net section and see if and what post is performed when it fails

Comment: can u try using a `<h:commandLink>` instead of `<h:outputLink>`

Comment: @roel - ill look for an error, but this happens at very low chance, so ill further investigate.

Comment: @Mango - nope <h:commandLink> does not work. it generates a post. :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This construct makes no sense. Make it a normal link

```html
<h:outputLink value="Page1.seam">
    <f:param name="m" value="n103" />
    <f:param name="mss" value="110" />
    <h:outputText value="Return to Page 1" />
</h:outputLink>
```

and to invoke an action on opening of the page, use `<f:event type="preRenderView">` in the target view instead.

```html
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{beanName.action}" />
```

#### See also:

- [How to execute action on GET request with f:viewParam?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647679/how-to-execute-action-on-get-request-with-fviewparam)
- [What can <f:metadata>, <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for)

Comment: by the way i'm still using JSF 1.2 so there is no f:event, what do you think is a better alternative for this. thanks :)

Comment: Ah thus you also don't have a `<f:viewParam>` to set the parameters. Use the bean's constructor or `@PostConstruct` instead.

Comment: @BalusC Can you please elaborate the reason when you say, `This construct makes no sense. Make it a normal link`. Why do you say so?

Comment: @Vikas: OP tried to send an idempotent request using ajax. This just doesn't make sense.